# jQuery change text nested in div, paragraph tag and strong tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to be able to reach out into the following html structure

```
 <div id="collection_propID214_formID1">
   <p class="fieldHeaderContainer">
       <strong>Add by ID:</strong>
   </p>
 </div>
```

And change the text inside of  tag, using jQuery. Is this possible?

Comment: `$('#collection_propID214_formID1 strong').text('Hello Wolrd!');`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could change the text of the `strong` tags inside the `div` using `.text()`.

Try this:

```
$('#collection_propID214_formID1 strong').text('Your text here');
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fftv4rxv/1/)**

Or

```
$('#collection_propID214_formID1').find('strong').text('Your text here');
```

**P.S:** If there are more than one strong elements, this would change the text for all.

Comment: It would be marginally more efficient to write -$('#collection_propID214_formID1').find('strong').text('Your text here'); - in both cases there is a risk of changing more text values than you intend if the collection_propID214_formID1 element contains more than one strong element.